# How to display waterway=riverbank so that islands can be subtracted or styled separately from the water?

Tags: qgis, quickosm

I'd like to style my river polygons and leave the islands as background color or a different color but I can't find a way to separate the inner relations from the main riverbank multipolygon.  I've tried a bunch of k:v pairs without being able to isolate the river and I'm still new with QGIS.  What is an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to run a separate query, but you can do it in the full **Query** tab of the QuickOSM window. They key thing is adding a **recurse** statement to the query. By doing so, we can tell the Overpass API to take our input set (a waterway=riverbank relation) and pull out any ways with the "inner" role.

Check out the [Overpass API page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#Recurse) on the OSM wiki for more details and other examples. Here's what my script looked like:

```
<osm-script output="json" output-config="" timeout="25">
  <query into="_" type="relation">
    <has-kv k="waterway" modv="" v="riverbank"/>
    <bbox-query s="42.724206716422" w="-87.817068099976" n="42.734987949903" e="-87.802391052246"/>
  </query>
  <recurse type="relation-way" role="inner" role-restricted="yes"/>
  <print e="" from="_" geometry="skeleton" ids="yes" limit="" mode="body" n="" order="id" s="" w=""/>
  <recurse from="_" into="_" type="down"/>
  <print e="" from="_" geometry="skeleton" ids="yes" limit="" mode="skeleton" n="" order="quadtile" s="" w=""/>
</osm-script>
```

And the output. The left is the basic k:v query, the right is with the additional recurse query layered over it.

[image]